# Redshift: Query cost from query plan to actual query execution time

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-execution-plan

The query plan in Redshift gives us cost estimation of a query.
My question is is there any way to map this cost into time? For example, if the query plan says that the cost is 100, is there anyway to say that the query execution time will be XX seconds. If query cost is 200 then the query will execute in approximately XXXX seconds.

I tried to figure out a mapping but could not. For example, I experimented with several queries:

```
       **Cost**     **Execution time in seconds**
Query1:1001847190981.69 ==20
Query2:1000022172472.15 ==5
Query3:7501104.80       ==1.5
Query4:12014890.19      ==6
Query5:1000010208097.13 ==2.87
```

You can see that there is no way to map query cost and execution time. Does anyone have any idea about this? Shouldnt it be a linear relationship? Like the more cost the more the execution time?

Comment: From what I read their documentation, cost is a relative value that "compares the relative execution times of the steps within a plan".  At one point I was thinking you might just establish your own baseline like you did in the example. But I would definitely ask AWS on their forum if it makes sense at all to establish such a baseline as the documentation says cost is relative only "within a plan". It seems that the main use is not to estimate execution time but rather identify expensive steps within a plan.